# SLICK 3.0 and postgres SQL: Apply `exists` on the result of SimpleFunction returning a list

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick-3.0

I have the following query in postgres:

```
select name from items where 'keyword' ~@@ any (string_to_array(name, ' '));
```

The `~@@` operator is a similarity operator from [pg_similarity module](https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity)

I would like to do this through Slick 3, I am stuck with applying the `any` function. Here is what I have so far:

```
// This query does a join on several tables including the items table   
// which I want to use for filtering
val similarTo = SimpleBinaryOperator[Boolean]("~@@")
val split = SimpleFunction.binary[String, String, List[String]]("string_to_array")
query = query.filter {
            case (_, item, _, _, _) => {
              split(item.name.toLowerCase, " "). // ? 
              // something like .exists(_ => similarTo("keyword", _)
            }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing eventually, in case someone from the future will have the same issue.

I put moved the filtering logic to the database :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION has_similar_word(name VARCHAR(300), keyword VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS  boolean AS $$
BEGIN

  -- a list of available similarity measures is available at:
  -- https://github.com/eulerto/pg_similarity

  set pg_similarity.jarowinkler_threshold = 0.85;

 RETURN keyword ~@@ any (string_to_array(name, ' '));
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and in slick, my query became like this:

```
val similarTo = SimpleFunction.binary[String, String, Boolean]("has_similar_word")
      query = query.filter {
        case (_, item, _, _, _) => {
          similarTo(item.name.toLowerCase, keyWordvariable)
        }
```

I would have preferred to keep logic just in my Scala code, but it seems to be not possible at the moment.